# Can I add an ElementHost to a regular WinForm StatusStrip?

Tags: wpf, winforms, statusstrip, toolstripbutton, windowsformsintegration

I just started learning WPF, and I've been trying to add this WPF control to a regular WinForm.

I know I can use `Forms.Integration.ElementHost` to host WPF controls in a WinForm. But as `StatusStrip` takes `Items` and not `Controls` it's marking the `ElementHost` as incompatible.

Do I need to replace the entire `StatusStrip` with WPF `ToolBar` for this to work?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `ToolStripControlHost` to host the element host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost(v=vs.110).aspx) to add any control to the strip. For example for an element host which hosts a wpf user control, you can use this code:

```
var host = new ToolStripControlHost(this.elementHost1);
this.statusStrip1.Items.Add(host);
```

Comment: Ohhh! It hosts a Control! I see! Thanks! Exactly what I needed!